# building android lite version - full and lite versions get mixed on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, version-control, build, setup-deployment

I'm trying to build lite version of an android project..so far, I've read that renaming application package (I've used eclipse option for renaming app package) should be enough. I've checked in manifest.xml, package is renamed, but when I install my app on phone (or on a emulator) it seams to mix somehow versions, specially after pressing home button and then re-entering the application (it switches to previously installed full version).

what am I missing? Is there something else to change in order to get different version of application? Should I change application name or maybe source packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing a package name you also need to change the name of your files. So if your app was originally `my.app.full` then the files under `src` will be `my/app/full`. If you change your package name to `my.app.lite` then you need to change the film names under `src` to `my/app/lite`.

Also at the top of all your classes you should have a package declaration ie. `package my.app.full`, which also needs to be changed to your new package name - `package my.app.lite`

If you are still having problems, try refreshing the build, and then if that doesn't work delete the `gen` file (don't worry it will reappear when you build your project)